# Will specialization of function templates in std for program-defined types no longer be allowed in C++20?

Tags: c++, std, template-specialization, function-templates, c++20

Quote from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std):

> **Adding template specializations**
>
> It is allowed to add template specializations for any standard library **|class (since C++20)|** template to the namespace std only if the declaration depends on at least one program-defined type and the specialization satisfies all requirements for the original template, except where such specializations are prohibited.

Does it mean, that starting from C++20, adding specializations of function templates to the `std` namespace for user-defined types will be no longer allowed? If so, it implies that many pieces of existing code can break, doesn't it? (It seems to me to be  kind-of a "radical" change.) Moreover, it will inject into such codes undefined behavior, which will not trigger compilations errors (warnings hopefully will).

Comment: Removed my previous comment, I would trust https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std

Comment: out of curiosity: did you ever feel like providing a specialization for `std::function` ?

Comment: @user463035818 functions in namespace `std::`, not `std::function`, which is a class template.

Comment: @Caleth misread the title ;)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As it stands now it definitly looks that way.  Previously [namespace.std] contained

> A program may add a template specialization **for any standard library template** to namespace std only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly prohibited.

While [the current draft states](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/namespace.constraints#namespace.std-2)

> Unless explicitly prohibited, a program may add a template specialization **for any standard library class template** to namespace std provided that (a) the added declaration depends on at least one program-defined type and (b) the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template.

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

And it looks like the paper [Thou Shalt Not Specialize std Function Templates!](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0551r0.pdf) by Walter E. Brown is responsible for it.  In it he details an number of reason why this should be changed such as:

> - Herb Sutter: “specializations don’t participate in overloading. [...] If you want to customize a function base template and want that
>     customization to participate in overload resolution (or, to always be
>     used in the case of exact match), make it a plain old function, not a
>     specialization. And, if you do provide overloads, avoid also providing
>     specializations.”
> - David Abrahams: “it’s wrong to use function template specialization [because] it interacts in bad ways with overloads. [...] For example,
>     if you specialize the regular `std::swap` for `std::vector<mytype>&`,
>     your specialization won’t get chosen over the standard’s vector
>     specific `swap`, because specializations aren’t considered during
>     overload resolution.”
> - Howard Hinnant: “this issue has been settled for a long time. . . . Disregard Dave’s expert opinion/answer in this area at your own
>     peril.”
> - Eric Niebler: “[because of] the decidedly wonky way C++ resolves function calls in templates. . . , [w]e make an unqualified call to
>     `swap` in order to find an overload that might be defined in [...]
>     associated namespaces[...] , and we do `using std::swap` so that, on
>     the off-chance that there is no such overload, we find the default
>     version defined in the std namespace.”
> - High Integrity C++ Coding Standard: “Overload resolution does not take into account explicit specializations of function templates. Only
>     after overload resolution has chosen a function template will any
>     explicit specializations be considered.”

Comment: Your draft citation only refers to class templates, not function templates.

Comment: @JonHarper I'm sorry but I don't understand the issue.  The text used to say *A program may add a template specialization
for **any standard library template** to namespace std*  Now it limits that by stating *a program may add a template specialization for any standard library **class template** to namespace* instead.

Comment: Just pointing out that the modifications are not part of the citation, i.e. there is no reference to the previous wording, making it unclear.

Comment: @JonHarper Okay.  I've updated the answer to show the current text of the standard for a comparison.

Answer (score 16):

Not really that radical. This change is based on [this paper from Walter E. Brown](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0551r3.pdf). The paper goes into rationale rather deeply, but ultimately it boils down to this:

1. Specialization of function templates is rather poor as a customization point. Overloading and ADL are much better in that regard. There are other customization points discussed in the paper as well.
2. The standard library doesn't rely on this poor customization point too much already.
3. The wording change that's put into place actually permits adding entire declarations to namespace std (not just specializations) where it's explicitly permitted. So now there are *better* customization points.

Given #1 and #2, it's rather unlikely existing code will break. Or at least, not enough for this to be a major problem. Code that used `auto` and `register` also "broke" in the past, but that minuscule amount of C++ code didn't stop progress.

Comment: Wait, so we'll able to add begin overloads to std tuple?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont - IDK if that's likely to be in the "explicitly allowed" set. I suspect most of those allowances will pertain to the ranges library and its customization points.

Comment: It absolutely does not permit adding overloads to `std`.