# Is it legit to define std::begin for const char*?

Tags: c++, string, string-comparison, string-view

I have a function for case insensitive comparison of strings which uses `std::lexicographical_compare` with custom comparator.

However i would like to be able to compare `strings`, `string_views` and `const char*` between each other, for maximum convenience and efficiency.

So i was thinking: What if i make a template, `std::string` has `begin`/`end`, `std::string_view` has `begin`/`end`, ... but `const char*` doesn't, not even in a form of non-member function.

So it is ok to define own `begin`/`end` overloads like this

```
namespace std {
    const char * begin(const char* str) { return str; }
    const char * end(const char* str) { return str + strlen(str); }
}
```

so that then i can compare everything with everything by

```
std::lexicographical_compare(std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::begin(b), std::end(b), icomp );
```

?

If not, how else could i solve my problem?

Comment: You never should put something into the `std` namespace. Use your own namespace instead.

Comment: Ahh yes, I remember the controversy when Bjarne Stroustrup first started using "legit" in the standard to talk about defined behavior. But in all seriousness, you should probably pick a more descriptive word for your title.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ There are [a few cases](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std) where you can declare in `namespace std`.

Comment: The only things you may add to the `std` namespace are tempate specializations.

Comment: @Youda008 Just make the function take a `std::string_view`.  Then it works with a `std::string`, `std::string_view`, `const char *`, or any class that provides an `operator string_view`..

Comment: you can easily get a `string_view` to a `const char *` I think this is one intended use of `string_view`  (which has `begin` and `end`)

Comment: Another alternative is to provide `begin()` and `end()` in your own namespace and then bring `std` by using directive

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, this is not legal, because `const char *` is not a user-defined type.

> The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or
>   definitions to namespace `std` or to a namespace within namespace `std`
>   unless otherwise specified. A program may add a template
>   specialization for any standard library template to namespace `std` only
>   if the declaration depends on a user-defined type and the
>   specialization meets the standard library requirements for the
>   original template and is not explicitly prohibited

[`[namespace.std/1]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.std#1)

You can instead declare those in some other namespace, such as `::`

```
const char * begin(const char* str) { return str; }
const char * end(const char* str) { return str + strlen(str); }
```

And use them with unqualified calls

```
std::lexicographical_compare(begin(a), end(a), begin(b), end(b), icomp );
```

Additionally, in C++20, it will be even more restrictive, permitting only class templates specialisations for program-defined types

> Unless otherwise specified, the behavior of a C++ program is undefined
>   if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace `std` or to a
>   namespace within namespace `std`.
>
> Unless explicitly prohibited, a program may add a template
>   specialization for any standard library class template to namespace
>   `std` provided that (a) the added declaration depends on at least one
>   program-defined type and (b) the specialization meets the standard
>   library requirements for the original template.

[`[namespace.std]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/constraints#namespace.std)

Comment: `std::begin` also isn't a class template.  Note that there is a breaking change going to C++20 where function specializations will no longer be allowed as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52760580/will-specialization-of-function-templates-in-std-for-program-defined-types-no-lo/52760860#52760860

Comment: I personally would not put them in the global namespace either (even though it is allowed). The chance for accidental usage by another developer is high. I would put in my own name space and make its usage explicit.