# What's the purpose of this function that does nearly nothing?

Tags: c++, rapidjson

I'm currently reading the code of [RapidJSON](https://github.com/Tencent/rapidjson/), and I don't understand this bit of code:

```
//! Reserve n characters for writing to a stream.
template<typename Stream>
inline void PutReserve(Stream& stream, size_t count) {
    (void)stream;
    (void)count;
}

//! Put N copies of a character to a stream.
template<typename Stream, typename Ch>
inline void PutN(Stream& stream, Ch c, size_t n) {
    PutReserve(stream, n);// I think this function does nothing
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        PutUnsafe(stream, c);
}
```

Can anyone explain the purpose of 'PutReserve' for me?

Comment: Maybe it will do something in a future patch?

Comment: Or did something in a previous version, for that matter

Comment: It could also be there to have a common interface.  There is a `PutReserve` in [here](https://github.com/Tencent/rapidjson/blob/7e68aa0a21b7800ec98133cb106e49bd6536e25c/include/rapidjson/stringbuffer.h) that actually does something so this could be a function that "does nothing if not implemented for that stream type function"

Comment: In some cases, functions that do nothing are meant to have "no-operation" functionality. Sometimes the function name is `noop`. This is needed in cases where you need to provide a function callback to something, but you don't necessarily have anything to do. So juts give it a function that does nothing.

Comment: Note `PutN` is a template which needs some functionality called `PutReserve`. By default it does noting, but there can be specialization of `PutReserve` template which it does something useful and is such case `PutN` will use alternative version.

Comment: @MarekR this looks like an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code allows others to specialize `PutReserve` for their own stream types. This gives other forms of streams the option to act on the information passed here - in this case, that `count` characters are about to be inserted into the stream.

You are correct that the repository has no such specialization right now, thus nothing will ever happen from this code alone. However, if this is intended as an option for extension by users (or future extension within the library), it still has a purpose. And if it remains unspecialized, the compiler will of course see that the function does nothing and completely optimize it away.

---

In practice, a user that wants to use this library with his `MyStream` type would specialize the function like this:

```
template<> void PutReserve(MyStream& stream, size_t count) {
  // ...user code
}
```

Note however that the C++ standard library is going to eliminate all forms of function template specialization (in `namespace std`) in a future C++ version, replacing them by functor classes as "customization points". See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52760580/will-specialization-of-function-templates-in-std-for-program-defined-types-no-lo) for the rationale.

Comment: Maybe you can explain a bit how this specialization is done, with a simple explanation and example of ADL with a custom stream type

Comment: thank you,does **the compiler will of course see that the function does nothing and completely optimize it away** can be relied on in production code?

Comment: @maidamai Yes. If you do optimized builds, of course.

Comment: This is a bit misleading because C++20 will not eliminate *overloading*, which can also be used to provide template customization points. However, such an overload cannot be in or under `namespace std` i.e. needs to be ADL-friendly. `swap`, `begin`, `end`, and some others are explicitly mentioned as customization points in this manner. The change mostly forbids (IMO) weird things like providing an explicit specialization of `std::sort`. Weird, among other things, because it only works with the exact types of iterators and e.g. comparison function.

Comment: @ArneVogel I clarified that part a bit. Yes, there are more customization points, but I meant to specifically talk about specializing `std` function templates.