# Is There a Way to Just Evaluate the Argument to a Functor?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, functor, negation

Given `foo` which is a `vector` I want to evaluate it's contents with [`all_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of). But all I'm really trying to check is that each element evaluates to `true`.

I can do this by using [`logical_not`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/logical_not) and `none_of` but I would rather not use double negatives, and it feels dumb to write a lambda: `[](const auto param) -> bool { return param; }`

Does the standard provide me a functor that does what I want?

Comment: Not sure where the downvote came from. I recall seeing a question about this some time ago. I think it will be possible eventually, or that's my recollection.

Comment: I think all the standard function objects can be found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/functional).

Comment: Never thought about it, but seems like an identity functor would be useful. Doesn't look like there is one.

Comment: `std::bind(std::equal_to<bool>{}, _1, true)` :) Lambda doesn't look that bad afterall...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`std::identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/identity) which was added to C++20.  It takes a parameter and returns it unchanged.  It `operator()` looks like

```
template<typename T>
constexpr T&& operator()( T&& t ) const noexcept;
```

and it returns

```
std::forward<T>(t)
```

Comment: How about just std::forward then?

Comment: @rubenvb You could but you would have to cast it to a function pointer which would look really ugly.

Comment: Ah yes the unfortunate overloaded function as functor story in templates algorithms.

Comment: @NathanOliver In addition to that, we will most likely no longer be allowed to take the address of `std::forward` (nor instances of most function templates in the standard library) starting from C++20, as [explained here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0551r3.pdf). (With credits to StoryTeller who [linked to the document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52760580/will-specialization-of-function-templates-in-std-for-program-defined-types-no-lo).)