# Refactor extended namespace std

Tags: c++, std, undefined-behavior, absolute-value

I have a large project where namespace std is extended with `std::abs` for a custom type like in the following example.

```
struct A {
    int a;
};

namespace std {
    template <int i>
    auto abs(A<i> const& x) -> A<i>
    {
        return A<i>(std::abs(x.a));
    }
}
```

From my understanding, this is undefined behaviour, as it is not a template specialisation for `std::abs`, so I would like to refactor this. Is there any way to reasonably do this? The call `std::abs(A<i>)` is often used.

Comment: A common way is not to call `std::abs` directly, but to use `using std::abs;` and then just call `abs`. This will find you custom `abs` even when it is not in `std`. Note that, since C++20, IIRC, you even cannot add specializations of function templates into `std`. This question is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6380862/580083. It is the same problem more commonly solved for `swap` function.

Comment: @DanielLangr You recall correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52760580/will-specialization-of-function-templates-in-std-for-program-defined-types-no-lo

Comment: So this would have to be changed at the call site?

Comment: Yes, all of your call sites are bad as this `abs` should not be in `std`.  Add it to the same namespace that `A` is defined in and then change the call sites to just use `abs` or `your_ns::abs`