# What's the use of <ratio> when we have contexpr values?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++20

The `<ratio>` header lets you uses template meta-programming to work with and manipulate [rational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number) values.

However - it was introduced in C++11, when we already had `constexpr`. Why is it not good enough to have a fully-constexpr'ifed library type for rationals, i.e. basically:

```c++
template<typename I>
struct rational { 
    I numerator;
    I denominator;
};
```

and use that instead?

Is there some concrete benefit to using [`std::ratio`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio/ratio) that C++11 constexpr functionality would not be well-suited enough for? And if so, is it still relevant in C++20 (with the expanded "reach" of constexpr)?

Comment: Ratios and rational numbers are different things. Ratios are commonly used by the [chrono](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) library for its [durations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration)

Comment: Not sure if it was part of the decision, but specializing library functions for custom types was removed from C++, where specializing types is still there.

Comment: Additionally, `constexpr` doesn't always guarantee compile-time evaluation. Template metaprogramming, pretty much does.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: That's true, but then you could wrap the library type with your own TMP "value" which does guarantee compile-time evaluation.

Comment: @NathanOliver  It wasn't completely removed.

Comment: @Spencer Specializing standard library functions was completely removed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52760580/will-specialization-of-function-templates-in-std-for-program-defined-types-no-lo/52760860#52760860

Comment: @NathanOliver We might just be dancing around definitions here?  Member functions of `std::numeric_limits` specializations could be construed as "specialzations of standard library functions".

Comment: @Spencer The standard only allows `a program may add a template specialization for any standard library class template` so that works as long as the limits specialization is for a custom type.

Comment: @NathanOliver  Yes, yes, I get that...it's just that the wording is vague and this is compounded by the fact that the Standard only prohibits them by omission.  There should be a [Note] explicitly mentioning `std::swap` since that was the most frequently specialized function.

Comment: @NathanOliver I used to joke about the (decidedly non-kosher) specialzation of swap for unsigned integers with the old 3-XOR version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there some concrete benefit to using std::ratio that C++11 constexpr functionality would not be well-suited enough for?

You can pass `ratio` as a template type argument, which is what [`std::chrono::duration`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) does. To do that with a value-based ratio, you need C++20 or newer.

In C++20 and newer I don't see any benefits of the current design.

Comment: One advantage is that `std::ratio` gives you *exact* representations of arbitrary fractions across the entire domain (within the data type range), whereas `double` doesn’t. How often that’s actually needed is another question (and it’s probably *not* neeed for `std::chrono::duration`, in particular).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I don't think OP proposes `double`? I think they suggest `template <typename T> struct ratio {T num, den;};`.

Comment: Oh I see, I think you’re right.

Comment: @einpoklum Done. :)

Comment: One benefit of the current design: types are significantly easier to deal with than values for metaprogramming purposes. For instance: `std::chrono::duration` works with Boost.Mp11 if ratio is a type parameter, but not if it's a value parameter.

Comment: @Barry: I'd say that values are significantly easier to deal with than types... at least as of C++20. Boost.Mp11 sounds like a C++11 library, while the answers point to C++20 as the point at which the current design is not beneficial.

Comment: Another comment is that for @HolyBlackCat is that we could, instead of passing the struct - pass in the two integers as two template parameters rather than as a compound type. That would work n C++11 but would be perhaps "uglier" than using `std::ratio`.

Answer (score 7):

There are several answers and comments here, but I think none of them really drives home the point of `std::ratio`. Let's begin with the definition of `std::ratio`. It is roughly equivalent to:

```
template<int Num, int Den>
struct ratio {
    static constexpr int num = Num;
    static constexpr int den = Den;
};
```

What you probably though, could be used as an alternative to `std::ratio` is something like the following:

```
template<typename I>
struct ratio {
    I num;
    I den;
};
```

with a bunch of `constexpr` functions to perform arithmetic with that type.

Note that there is a subtle but very important difference between the two definitions. Whereas in the second one the actual values of the ratio (`num` and `den`) are stored in the **instances** of the type, in the first definition the values are actually stored in the **type** itself.

If you have a library like `std::chrono`, you want for example a type, that can store a time as a number of milliseconds (e.g. `std::chrono::milliseconds`). If you later want to convert this number into seconds, you do not want to encode the conversion ratio into the instance of `std::chrono::milliseconds` but rather into the type itself. That is the reason why `std::chrono` uses the first form instead of the second (or a simple floating point value).

To store a number into a type and not the instance, you need a [*non-type template parameter*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter). Before C++20 you only could use integral values for non-type template parameters. To nevertheless store rational conversion factors the standard library, specified the `std::ratio` class template.

With C++20 the tides changed a little bit, as you now can use floating point numbers as non-type template arguments. For example the `std::chrono::duration` could be rewritten like:

```
template<..., double conversion_factor, ...>
duration {
    ...
};
```

This C++20 feature has however nothing to do with "expanded reach of constexpr"
that you mentioned in your question. Compilation time calculation is different from storing numerical values in the type itself, although you need the first to do the second.

The use of the `std::ratio` class template is made (exclusively) for storing values into the type.

Comment: "you do not want to encode the conversion ratio into the instance of std::chrono::milliseconds" I wouldn't do that, obviously.

Comment: @einpoklum I do not see how you would avoid that without using a `std::ratio`-like construct before C++20.

Comment: [You would still use `ratio`, not `double`](https://godbolt.org/z/xsM4fovTK).

Answer (score 0):

[`boost::rational`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/rational/) was provided about the same time as [`boost::ratio`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/ratio.html). However since the later was used by [`boost::chrono`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/chrono.html) which was in turn used by [`boost::thread`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/thread.html), it was easier to add the whole bunch together to the standard. If one seeks a full-fledged run-time usable rational number class, [`boost::rational`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/rational/) is there. The [`boost::multiprecision`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html) is also available to provide very long integral types as the argument for [`boost::rational`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/rational/). Regarding the standardization of other parts of boost such as [`boost::random`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost_random.html), it has been a big question to me why [`boost::rational`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/rational/) is not yet added to to standard library.

Regards,
FM.

Comment: Add links please...

Comment: @einpoklum just click on boost everywhere.